# A Generalization of Goldbach’s Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, conjectures, goldbachs-conjecture

The [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture)
 is that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \ \exists p,q \in \mathcal{P}$ such that $2n=p+q$.

I wonder if there are some generalization giving more information about the congruence satisfied by $p,q$, for example

> Given $m ,a\in \mathbb{N},gcd(a,m)=1$, for every $  n \equiv a \pmod{m}$ large enough, $\exists p,q \in \mathcal{P}$ such that $2n=p+q$ and $p\equiv q \equiv a \pmod{m}$

Is there some reference on this, and is it much harder than the original Goldbach's conjecture ?

The Nature of the Φ(m) Function  http://www.vixra.org/abs/1911.0111

Comment: MO post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/252597/a-generalization-of-goldbach-s-conjecture-2n-pq-p-equiv-q-equiv-a-pmod

Comment: You might have a look at advice on cross-posting given [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) and in other discussions on meta tagged ([meta-tag:cross-posting]).

Comment: The Generalized Goldbach's Conjecture : Symmetry of Prime Number https://globaljournals.org/GJSFR_Volume14/3-The-Generalized-Goldbachs-Conjecture.pdf